# How to make a view in a XIB/storyboard size to the phone dimensions without using auto layout

Tags: ios

I have a scroll view in a storyboard and the app is to run on iPhone4s and iPhone5s with iOS5 and iOS6.
I initially created the storyboard and was running on an iPhone5 and now I'm testing with an iPhone4.

Isn't there a way of just using a single storyboard for both the iPhone4 and iPhone5 and the when views etc. will automatically resize themselves depending upon the device, or do I have to use two separate storyboards?

I've tried numerous things, such as changing the simulated metrics size and many others but I can't find anyway of the view changing its size automatically - as I created the storyboard initially for an iPhone 5 the view now seems stuck at a 548 height when loaded. SUrely there must be a way of specifying in the storyboard that its height comes from the device? (Its height is the full screen less the status screen).

### Further details

There is  UIScrollView inside a UIView, the UIView will resize, the UIScrollView will not:[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in the "Size Inspector", inside the Utilities menu. There you can set the autosizing and origin of any visible element.

This works in iOS 5 and 6 and it's not required to use the Autolayout, which is only for iOS 6.

Size inspector:

[image: Size Inspector]

Second screenshot:

[image: View resize]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the relevant part please

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a screenshot. Note that you can "test" the layout using the button of the second screenshot (bottom-right corner of the interface builder).

Comment: Thanks, I've played around with this but can't get it to change - the height is set as a certain value (in black, not grey). And nothing I can will make it change (other than typing in by hand, which defeats the purpose). How do I get the height to change its value automatically? THere are other elements where the height is in gray and does change as I toggle the button in the second screenshot. What determines whether the values are grey and variable or black and fixed?

Comment: You want to change the height of a button, for example? Click the button and in the size inspector, "autosizing" part, click the vertical arrows (inside the "box") to make them red (this makes the box to enlarge vertically). Of course, for it to work, you have to "fix" the distance with above/below elements (that's the purpose of the outer lines).

Comment: Its for a scroll view, and the autosizing arrows are already clicked, like in your screenshot.

Comment: My scroll view is contained within another view (a UIView), that outer view's height changes between 460 and 548 as I toggle device sizes, however for the scroll view it doesn't change - its always 548. Why will it change for the outer UIView view but not the inner UIScrollView?

Comment: That's a screenshot of one of my apps, it does not represent a solution for your particular problem (it was meant to show you the Size Inspector only). The inner view is, as you have noticed, another view. This has to be done for every view you want to resize.

Comment: Since the scroll view is inside an expanding view, select the scroll view and go to that "Autosizing" box in the screenshot. Click ALL the elements, the side elements and the horizontal and vertical arrows so that they're red and not faded. That should do it for you.

Comment: Joel I've tried clicking all 4 arrows and its still the same. For both of you I'll add some screenshots.

Comment: Also click the four outer elements for the inner view (leave everything in red).

Comment: I've added some screenshots - see how the size of the UIView is grey and thus will resize, but the size of the UIScrollView is black and is fixed. In this screenshot all 4 of the autosizing arrows for the UIScrollView are selected, previously it was the top and left ones selected. But its the same outcome regardless.

Comment: Ok, if I click the outer arrows nothing happens, if I click the inner arrows then I can see something changing. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! The inner arrows are what I was talking about. Glad it's working!

Answer (score -2):

You have to use two storyboards for iphone4 and iphone5. Then you can check the device size to load the .xib according to it.